# How to fit image to Thumbnail canvas size?

Tags: thumbnails, images, post-thumbnails

I need to upload images with a different orientation (portrait and landscape) and I don't want to crop post-thumbnails. But I need always thumbnail size `250x250px`.

If I upload a portrait oriented image - it will be resized to **250px height**, but the width may be different. And conversely - if I load landscape oriented image - it will be resized to **250px width**, but height will be set proportional.

This is what I need:

I need thumbnail size to be always **250x250px**. If I upload portrait image - it must be resized to height: **250px** and placed in the center of thumbnail canvas. etc...

[image]

Comment: Is this the built in thumbnail size? Do you have the "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions" box checked under Settings > Media?

Comment: I don't need to crop images. I need ti fit it in thumbnail canvas size.

Comment: So when you say "I need thumbnail size to be always 250x250px", you mean proportional within a maximum of 250x250?

Comment: U have upload picture in my question to illustrate what I need...

Comment: `object-fit: contain` or `background-size: contain` might help if you did this from CSS. I also saw a image size hack a while back that might give you some ideas - https://codepad.co/snippet/hPniZA6n

Comment: By default the WordPress cropping functionality won't generate the image that you're after. With a little css you could wrap an image with a div and style the background color. Beware of using `object-fit: contain`, It won't work in IE less than Edge without a poyfill and it won't work in Edge at all (yet).

Comment: Thanks for advise - I can do what I need with CSS-3 object-fit: contain

Answer (score -1):

I would try adding

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 250, false );
```

In the theme's functions.php.

(see codex on [Setting Thumbnail Size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Set_the_Post_Thumbnail_Size))